# Bash script line 106: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This is my first script so please be gentle. I know the unexpected end of file syntax error is usually an if without a fi, for without a done or missing quotes etc. I cannot find any of the above. I have a feeling it might be the part of the code where I am trying to write to file httpd.conf with echo, but I am not sure. Can anybody spot whats wrong, tips, suggestions? Thank you.

```
enter code here#!/bin/bash


INSTALL_DIRECTORY=/home/jared
export INSTALL_DIRECTORY
cd ; pwd

#If statement to create directories if they are not made
    if test -d apache2 && if test -d www2
        then
            echo "Directories already exist" 
    else
        mkdir apache2 www2
    fi

cd apache2

#If statement to create files if they are not made
    if test -d bin
        then
            echo "Directory already exists"
    else
        mkdir bin
    fi

    if test -d conf
        then
            echo "Directory already exists"
    else
        mkdir conf
    fi

    if test -d lib
        then
            echo "Directory already exists"
    else
        mkdir lib
    fi

    cd /home/jared/www2

    if test -d html
        then
            echo "Directory already exists"
    else
         mkdir html
    fi

    if test -d cgi-bin
        then
            echo "Directory already exists"
    else
        mkdir cgi-bin
    fi

    if test -d ftp
        then
            echo "Directory already exists"
    else
        mkdir ftp
    fi


#Changing the permissions
chmod -R 755 apache2 ; chmod -R 750 www2
cd www2 ; chmod 722 ftp ; cd ../apache2/bin

#Creating the files
touch httpd ; chmod 755 httpd ; cd /home/jared/www2/html
touch index.html ; chmod 644 index.html ; cd ../cgi-bin
touch process.pl ; chmod 711 process.pl

cd ; cd /home/jared/apache2/conf

#Creating the httpd.conf file if it does not already exist
#and adding details

    if test -s httpd.conf
        then
            echo "File already exists"
    else
        echo '#
    #This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.It contains
    #configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
    #Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.
    #
    ServerRoot "/home/jared/apache1"
    #
    #DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will server your documents.
    #
    DocumentRoot "/home/jared/www1"' > /home/jared/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
    fi

chmod 644 /home/jared/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

echo $INSTALL_DIRECTORY
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Btw: Bourne-Shell (sh) is not Bourne-again shell (bash).

Comment: I went to shellcheck as mentioned and I have no idea what is wrong

Comment: @Cyrus Hmm so I need to change sh to bash? I will try that thank you

Comment: $ shellcheck myscript
 
Line 9:
    if test -d apache2 && if test -d www2
    ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this if expression.
 
Line 98:

^-- SC1050: Expected 'then'.
^-- SC1072: Expected 'then'. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if test -d apache2 && if test -d www2
```

should be

```
if test -d apache2 && test -d www2
```

Comment: That was it Thank you